# Ionic window.Connection is undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am working with Ionic and trying to check internet connection status. But it says window.Connection is undefined. I am connected to a wifi network. How can I get the correct internet status?

I have installed this plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

And this is my controller.

```
$scope.checkInternetConnection=function(){
            var con=window.Connection;
            console.log(con);
            if(window.Connection) {
                if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
                    console.log("No");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Yes");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you checking that inside a browser ?

Answer (score 3):

you are using an old version of the plugin. I can tell because you are using the old spelling.

You want:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

That plugin documentation is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-network-information).

Also, source your "core" plugins from [this list](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html). The plugins are retrieved via on NPM. Which, if you don't know you should be using NPM for your package management. So, if you do not know, read [Cordova Plugins Registry becomes immutable](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/09/08/cpr-readonly.html) (08 Sep 2015)

Lastly, this FAQ might help with some of the thorny issue you are going to find. I recommend you read the bold sentences and read the details as you need them.

[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Lastly, if you are going to use the network, you will need to understand the "whitelist" system, READ: [Whitelist Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html)